# Block Bots visiting paid URLs

Tags: laravel, bots, ip-blocking

I have Laravel application which is serving some content from external links, paid links. Problem is that bots are visiting all those links and gettting bill at end of a month is not so fun when those bots make 100000 requests.

How can i restrict access for bots and other unwanted visitors?

Comment: This is a cat-and-mouse game -- unless the folks on the other side are fairly naive and will just go on to easier prey when you make your site harder to scrape, the level of complexity in filtering for humans tends to increase over time (as you build countermeasures, the scrapers build counter-countermeasures; at some point you end up deploying CAPTCHAs and they're hiring people on Mechanical Turk to defeat them, etc). Winning that war doesn't really fit into the scope of a SO question -- consider hiring an engineer who's done this before, if it's worth real money to you.

Comment: True! For unwanted visitors I actually have a specific rule set e.g. when they hit 4000 requests, which is 250%+ more than average user make, they are automaticly added to blacklist and blocked. But for bots that is not something I would like.

Comment: maybe 4000 is too many (and yet too little What if someone just really likes your site, now the yare banned.) How about if they make more than 1 request per second, they are blocked and have to complete a captcha.

Comment: This is absolutely option to consider. While it provides a solution, some users might consider leaving such page. I count myself in one of those users who dont like capthas.

Comment: Have you tried putting cloudflare in front of the site to see if it mitigates the number of bots getting through? I think they help with that somewhat even on the free plan

Comment: I have never used cludflare before. Will review their documetation to see what they offer.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with @CharlesDuffy, now if you want something simple you could modify the way Laravel limit rate request. Check [this package](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle) made by [Graham Campbell](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell).

Comment: Just checked this library, but this way I will only limit requests down to a number which won't affect normal users. I am looking for a solution which will completely block bots visiting some specifi URLs.

Comment: Like @Charlesduffy said, is very hard to avoid this kind of behavior. You could limit the rate visiting by IP address so users can visit the indicated pages to a maximum X times your page per day/hour/minute

Comment: Uff that is something I just can't do. Normal users can't be limited. I asked here for answers because this is not my problem only, its some kind of a general problem affecting all similar websites. But yes, it is hard to avoid this kind of behavior.

Comment: The problem is how you difference a user than a bot?

Comment: At the moment some major bots are added to whitelist, but there is still problem with less know bots. Some of them don't even respect atributes on links, robots file...

Answer (score 0):

You should only allow authenticated users to access those premium links using the auth middleware on the appropriate route in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('linkWhichCostsYouMoney', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

See the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication).

You could also try disallowing robots to access the paid pages using [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html). This will only stop good bots, not bad bots.

Finally, depending on your application, it may be possible to cache the content locally and avoid using the paid service for every single request. If you want search engines to index your pages including paid content, this is the path you should follow.

Comment: This could work, but I am loading images and extra text for my users. If they won't see content until they are logged in, they will probably leave and use our competitor websites. Bad for bussines :D.

Comment: Maybe show them the bill in a blog post and they will understand

Comment: I am not sure they would like to see that kind of information

Comment: @Tim Why would you only want to block bots from accessing paid links? And not regular users?

Comment: On paid links I load content like description and images which are relevant for regular users.

Comment: but users don't have to log in ever?

Comment: is it feasible to share the url of the site?

Comment: Yes they do log in, and it is not. Here is the thing. Website is selling some trips , similar to booking, yet different. I cant force them to log, and I have to show the content.